# distinguish [ӕ] from [ɑ]

Tags: pronunciation

My mother tongue, Korean, has no sounds for /ӕ/ and /ɑ/; *ㅐ* and *ㅏ* are a bit similar to each of them respectively. So it’s very hard to catch those sounds. Would you let me know what sound does the [audio](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/143) make for *valuable*?

- /vӕljuəbl/
- /vɑljuəbl/

Comment: It's the first one: **væljʊəb(ə)l**. Take a look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70927)

Comment: The vowel in the stressed syllable is, as Dream Eater says, /ӕ/. The part representing orthographic <ua> however is not pronounced as two vowels or  a diphthong (in fact practically nobody says it that way) but a single unstressed vowel—I *think* the [reduced rounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Reduced_vowels_in_the_close_rounded_area) vowel [ʊ̈]. So: **/vӕljʊ̈bl/**

Comment: @StoneyB- I think when I say that word it depends on what I want it to mean.  If I say, "That watch is valuable" I say it as you've described with a [jʊ̈].  But if I want to say that soemthing is capable of being appraised then it is *value-able* (Granted it's not often that I get to use that second pronunciation.)

Comment: @Jim  I agree as to both the alternative pronunciation and its infrequent necessity. :)

Comment: @DreamEater If you are actually providing an answer to the question (as you have above) please post it as an answer and not as a comment.  This question is staying on the unanswered list because there is no Answer for the asker to accept (even though the question has been answered in the comments).

Comment: All your "distinguish /ӕ/ and /ɑ/" questions seem to be before /l/. I know that in American English, these vowels are altered slightly before /l/. This may also be true in British English, and may be confusing you. If this is also true in Korean, it would be really confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to [@Yes I use MUMPS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/distinguish-from?noredirect=1#comment5741_3477) comment, I'll just put my (and @StoneyB's) comments as answers.

The pronunciation is **væljʊəb(ə)l**.  See [this EL&U answer by John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70938):

> The letter *æ* was used in Old English to represent the vowel that's pronounced in Modern English *ash, fan, happy,* and *last:* /æ/. Mostly we now spell that vowel with the letter **a**, because of the [Great Vowel Shift](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler//GreatVowelShift.pdf).
>
> When *æ* appears in writing Modern English, it's meant to be a font
>   variant of *ae*, and is pronounced the same as that sequence of vowel
>   letters would be.

The vowel in the stressed syllable is **/ӕ/**. The part representing orthographic `<ua>` however is not pronounced as two vowels or a diphthong (in fact practically nobody says it that way) but a single unstressed vowel—I think the [reduced rounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Reduced_vowels_in_the_close_rounded_area) vowel [ʊ̈].